# Inrush Current Booster

Tags: motor, driver, inrush-current

I probably need help more with terminology (and thus, how to find the answer that already exists) than with technology.

My current hobby project is a low-power device — max current is 100mA at 5V* — which is intended to be a pneumatic water level sensor. The basic operation is to drive a small air pump for a very brief period (about 200ms), wait a moment, then read the pressure, repeating these steps until subsequent pressure readings differ by less than the error margin of the pressure sensor.

The catch is that there is so little current available that the pump sometimes stalls at that tipping point between poles. It's a 6V rated motor which I've successfully driven at voltages as low as 3V. At 5V it draws about 150mA when running (measured on a slow-sampling multimeter).

Being naive and still young enough to know everything, I'm thinking of adding a largish capacitor between the power rails, with a resistor in series to charge it up. For example I might use 100µF with 1kΩ, which at 5V should keep the charging current below 50mA, more than enough to keep the power supply happy. Then "crowbar" the resistor out with a FET that is turned on when the pump needs to be driven (not that "crowbar" is a term that really applies to currents in the order of 100mA).

I probably need some other kind of device (maybe a P-channel FET?) for the crowbar, since it's going to be turned "on" by bringing the gate voltage from below the source up to the same as the drain (Vgs will either be negative or zero):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEiXcX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My main question is: what is the terminology for this kind of setup where I'm intentionally catering to the high current inrush of the pump motor with a power supply that can't deliver that current?

Secondary questions: is what I'm doing in any way "normal" or sensible? Are there some references I should read up on before proceeding further with this project?

- the power supply is a solar LiPo charger with a USB 1.0 output, so 5V at a maximum of 100mA.

Comment: The current your pump is using is likely to increase as you build up pressure.

Comment: This isn't going to do what you want because M2 needs to have its' gate voltage to be at least 3V above the source.  In other words, you need at least 8V to drive M2 into full conduction.

Answer (score 1):

> At 5V it draws about 150mA when running

That's a power of 0.75 watts.

> The basic operation is to drive a small air pump for a very brief
>   period (about 200ms)

That's an energy of 0.75 watts x 0.2 seconds = 150 mJ.

Using a capacitor charged at 5V means it must hold possibly ten times the energy needed to be supplied to avoid the terminal voltage dropping too low when the motor is connected.

Let's say the capacitor needs to hold 1.5 joules at 5 volts. Energy held by a capacitor is: -

E = \$\dfrac{CV^2}{2}\$ so rearranging and inserting the numbers we get: -

Capacitance = 120,000 uF.

You are probably about 100 times out in your expectations. So maybe you could use a 120,000uF cap? How long would it take to charge that cap to 5V from dead with 100mA.

Q = CV and rearranging

\$\dfrac{dQ}{dt} = C \dfrac{dv}{dt}\$ = current = 100mA

Time to reach 5 volts = 0.12 farads x 5 volts divided by 0.1 amps = 6 seconds.

That sounds OK because this is just to get the big cap charged up to 5 volts - you'll only be taking 0.15 joules in 0.2 seconds and I guess, if you did the math it will take something like 0.5 seconds to recharge the cap to the full 5V before you need to activate the motor again but this may still be too long?

---

EDIT - can you use the 100mA from your power source AND the power that the capacitor can deliver to get this working as you hope? It's going to be a trade-off - you can't steal power to the motor without extending capacitor charge time. It's also very easy to over-estimate the ability of the motor given the low currents assumed.

Comment: I think that you are missing that the OP wants the capacitor to be large enough to just get the motor spinning.  In other words, just enough to kick the motor over.  He says that he has enough current available to keep the motor running once it has started.

Comment: @DwayneReid I think the OP is not realizing that the current he thinks he has might well be needed to charge the cap back to 5V but I'll make that clearer. Thanks

Comment: @DwayneReid is on the ball, I just need to cope with the inrush current and a little extra.

One the motor has been run for a fraction of a second, the system has "plenty" of time to recharge the capacitor.

Given the figures above I'm wondering what I've missed though, since what I have now is just a 10µF electrolytic stuck across the power rails.

Comment: @ManicDee I don't share your optimism.

Comment: My misplaced optimism was due to the pump motor working in some cases but not others. It turns out that there are ritual sacrifices and moon phases to consider. My power is supplied through a USB power bank capable of 350mA. That is then "regulated" through a diode and linear regulator so what I really end up with is 4.8 volts. Then there is the issue of USB cables being made out of wet spaghetti, so depending on which cable I have plugged in (cables plural too, since the power bank passes through any current that is supplied to charge it), so sometimes what I have is actually 3.8V :(

Comment: So I am kicking up a notch and trying my hand at a capacitor voltage doubler, with two small "buckets" lifting the supply to double the voltage in a much larger capacitor. This turns out to be difficult since all the references I can find for voltage doublers are plagiarised from Wikipedia, and nobody has an actual circuit that works. Will report back when I make progress/give up ;)

Comment: Show the doubler circuit and include the power oscillator dude.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIwFw7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice that the only difference between what I drew and what you have is that I swapped the location of the resistor that charges the capacitor.

HOWEVER - why do you need to switch the capacitor in and out of circuit in the first place?  Why can't it just be permanently in circuit?

Comment: I want the capacitor's energy dissipated by the motor, not the resistor. The resistor is only there to reduce the current drawn to charge the capacitor. Thank you for your suggestion of inverting the capacitor/resistor.

Comment: http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5355 - in this document there is a simpler version of my idea, having a reverse-biased diode parallel to the resistor. Thus the resistor is present to limit capacitor charge current while the diode allows discharge of the capacitor with a small voltage drop.